# migration from SO to Meta failed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, migrated-questions

I thought I just cast the fifth vote to close->migrate->meta on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815519/posting-code-in-this-forum

But the question doesn't appear to have migrated. (I flagged it for moderator migration after the migration failed to happen automatically, so it might be migrated by a moderator in the meantime.)

Bug?

Comment: Were all of the other 4 listed as "belongs on meta" when you voted to close? It only migrates when there's 4 or 5 votes to migrate to that site.

Comment: @animuson: yes, there was a happy little `4` in the blue box.

Comment: Here's a [screen capture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/feWQL.jpg) of the weirdness.

Comment: @animuson: crazy. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: Just because there's a 4 in the box doesn't mean that all 4 of those people voted for *migration*. If two of them simply voted to close as "off-topic" without selecting a migration destination, it would not have been migrated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the code attempts to migrate a question, one of the things it checks is the tags on the question and whether they fit on the destination site.

The question as it is on Stack Overflow is only tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).  This tag does not exist here.  The migration process strips this tag out since it doesn't exist on the destination site, which leaves it with no valid tags.  Due to this, the question is closed as off-topic instead of being migrated.

We do this to prevent a backdoor for creating tags that don't belong on the site, and to stop migrations that don't belong on the destination site in the first place.

Moderators are able to override this check when doing a migration, so you can flag these for moderator attention if something does need to be moved.

**EDIT**

**When a meta is the destination, the above tag checks are now skipped and the migration should proceed.**

For all other migrations, the "one tag must exist on target site" requirement is still in effect, e.g. SO -> SU.

Comment: I should also point out that questions will not get migrated if the user is banned from asking questions on the target site.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison can mods override that, similar to mods overriding the check for the tags thing?

Comment: @studiohack: Nope. I tried it once on Stack Apps and it failed.

Comment: That's a positive change; +1 for ninjas.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and thanks for the new rule.