# Questions closed with majority of votes pointing to migration are not migrated

Tags: bug, off-topic, review

While going through close votes review queue I've noticed that one of the questions had most of the votes pointing to a particular site (superuser in [this example](https://serverfault.com/q/352500/55663) if I remember correctly), but after closing the question it hasn't been automatically migrated.

I think that migrating the question is much more polite to the user, especially when it clearly *is* a good question just doesn't belong to the particular site.

Comment: It takes at least 4 votes to the target. Furthermore, at least one tag must exist on the destination site and the OP must not be question-banned.

Comment: @Mysticial: Then I think that the requirements are too strict, a majority (3) votes should be enough (especially so, as it's easy to not select the destination site when marking the question as off-topic)

Comment: @Mysticial are you sure about the one tag thing? First I've heard that, but the other two are true (and for good reason IMO)

Comment: @BenBrocka I remember someone (possibly a mod) mentioning that. But I can't remember where. I have (intentionally) edited in a tag on the destination site before casting a migrate vote - to make sure that it actually does migrate.

Comment: @BenBrocka I _think_ the tag thing is not a requirement when a mod is involved in the closure, which might explain why you haven't stumbled upon this one yet.

Comment: @BenBrocka: 'Tis true, if the question has [no tags in common](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126479) with the migration target, it doesn't go through automatically. -- I thought there was something about not auto-migrating old questions, but I'm having a hell of a time finding *anything* about the auto-migration conditions on Meta...

Comment: @HubertKario If I'm not horribly mistaken it used to be 3 migration votes, and was changed to 4 when it became apparent that most people thought it was "nice" to offload crap questions to other sites instead of closing them.

Comment: FYI: The user already asked the exact same question on Super User 2 days later: http://superuser.com/questions/381893/fix-an-ad-hoc-network-hosted-by-a-windows-xp-machine-problems-with-mtu - The migration is not needed anyways. Just delete the Server Fault question.

Comment: @YannisRizos: if it was 3 in the past then I kind of see a problem. Maybe then off-topic form should have a "none of the above" instead of just preselected "off-topic"?

Comment: @HubertKario ...or just remove the option to migrate.

Comment: @YannisRizos: sorry but I don't understand what you mean by that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What [Mysticial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/169611/mysticial) said is correct. The question is migrated if:

- [Four users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97700/140449) voted to migrate it to the same site
- The question is using at least one tag used in the destination site
- The OP must not have a question-ban in the destination site

Failing one of the conditions, the question can be flagged to be migrated. Keep in mind that not all the questions are migrated. The first rule for migration is, "don't migrate crap"; it means that, e.g., a not constructive question will not migrated. If then the question is on-topic on the site where it is asked, it is probably the moderators will not migrate the question, if it is not the OP asking for the migration.

Also, not even moderators can migrate a question that is 30 days old. This is a recent change that has been introduced to avoid migration "hot potato" style.

This is not a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug); it's [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).